# What are the benefits of using a better hammer in A Township Tale (VR)?

Tags: meta-quest-2, a-township-tale

Im **very** new to A Township Tale, I started learning carpentry and blacksmithing recently, and a random question entered my head while I was making a new axe, what are the benefits of putting in the work for a better hammer (copper, iron, etc.) if you can make a primitive hammer in two minutes to do it?

Of course there's the durability increase but besides that I can't find or think of any other benefits, since the primitive ones get the job done just as well. Im asking specifically for the hammer since I found the benefits for other tools like pickaxes and axes obviously, but couldn't find any for the hammer which only made me wonder more.

I am in the Oculus Quest 2 version because I heard there can be differences between the PC version and VR version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hammers for forging get more efficient as you use better metals.

Using a basic copper hammer will take more hits than one made with better materials when forging the same blade.

The size of the sparks/effect that appear will tell you of the efficiency. Besides metal temperature and strike power, the hammer material is the final piece to get maximum forging efficieny.

Comment: The better the metal the less hits it takes to forge something?

Comment: yes, for example, (i'm just making numbers up). let's say you forge a copper axe head with a rusty hammer. It takes 8 hits. Now you use a copper smith's hammer, this time it takes 5 hits. Assuming swing strength and the axe head's temperature are the exact same in both instances.

Comment: Makes sence, thanks for telling me how they work.